# Aerospike NodeJS UDF Aggregation Error

Tags: node.js, lua, udf, aerospike

I've created an aggregate function which works in aerospike which works in AQL:

```
AGGREGATE filter2.check_teamId('123', 0, 1456499994597) ON analytics.tracking 
WHERE teamId = '123'
```

This returns results.
I'm then trying to use the same UDF in NodeJS:

```
var statement = {
    aggregationUDF: {module: 'filter2', funcname: 'check_teamId', 
    arg:['123', 0, 1456499994597]}
};

var query = client.query('analytics', 'tracking', statement);
var stream = query.execute();
```

The result is a seemingly uninformative error:

```
{ code: 100,
  message: 'UDF: Execution Error 1',
  func: 'as_query_aggregate',
  file: 'src/main/aerospike/aerospike_query.c',
  line: 903 }
```

The server logs state:

> Feb 28 2016 22:33:58 GMT: INFO (scan): (scan.c::933) starting
>   aggregation scan job 1201452721893048027 {analytics:tracking}
>   priority 2
>
> Feb 28 2016 22:33:58 GMT: INFO (scan): (scan.c::1026)
>   finished aggregation scan job 1201452721893048027 (0)

Does anyone have any tips for getting a UDF to work with NodeJS?
Or any ideas how to diagnose the error?

I have set the user UDF location in the config which does not affect the result.

UPDATE:
Here is the lua code:

```
local function map_profile(record)
  return map {interaction=record.interaction, 
              teamId=record.teamId, datetime=record.datetime, 
              timestamp=record.timestamp, version=record.version, 
              interactions=record.interactions}
end
function check_teamId(stream, teamId, startDate, endDate)
  local function filter_teamId(record)
    return record.teamId == teamId and 
           record.timestamp >= startDate and record.timestamp <= endDate
  end
  return stream : filter(filter_teamId) : map(map_profile)
end
```

Comment: What is the code for the `check_teamId` UDF?

Comment: Also, you have a `WHERE` clause in the AQL statement but no `filters` section in your statement object in the Node.JS version.

Comment: Thanks @AdamB. Updated with the lua code above. The WHERE clause is not actually required, and the query runs fine without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason that you are getting the UDF execution error (code: 100) is that the system and/or user path for the LUA subsystem are not setup correctly. If you turn on debug logging for the client you might see one or both of these error messages:

```
Apr 04 2016 08:15:19 UTC: DEBUG(45951) [conversions.cc:248] [config_from_jsobject] - Could not find a valid LUA system path ./aerospike-client-c/package/usr/local/aerospike/client/sys/udf/lua/
Apr 04 2016 08:15:19 UTC: DEBUG(45951) [conversions.cc:273] [config_from_jsobject] - Could not find valid LUA user path ./aerospike-client-c/package/usr/local/aerospike/client/usr/udf/lua
```

If the client cannot determine the correct path automatically, then you have to pass the system/user path in the configuration. (See below.)

But there is another problem with your UDF invocation in the Node.js client. The arguments for the UDF should be passed in the `args` element of the `aggregationUDF` object, not in `arg`.

Here is a complete example that works for me:

```
const Aerospike = require('aerospike')

const config = {
  hosts: '192.168.33.10:3000',
  log: { level: 5 },
  modlua: {
    userPath: './',
    systemPath: './node_modules/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/lua/'
  }
}

Aerospike.connect(config, (error, client) => {
  if (error) throw error

  var statement = {
    aggregationUDF: {
      module: 'agg',
      funcname: 'check_teamId',
      args: ['123', 0, 1456499994597]
    }
  }
  var query = client.query('test', 'tracking', statement)
  var stream = query.execute()

  var count = 0
  stream.on('error', (error) => console.error('error:', error))
  stream.on('data', (result) => {
    count++
    console.log('result:', result)
  })
  stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('found %d records', count)
    client.close()
  })
})
```

Note that this example uses the `aerospike@2.0.0-alpha.1` client version that was just [released](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/early-adopter-release-for-aerospike-node-js-client-v2-0/). But the setup and execution of a UDF query is identical with the v1.x client.

I have also uploaded this example to Github [here](https://gist.github.com/jhecking/3aeb47ed6adba291f9039ce7c92b04cc). This Gist also includes a `setup.js` script to create some sample records based on what your `map_profile` function expects.

Feel free to follow up on this in our [user forum](https://discuss.aerospike.com/c/client-libraries/node-js-client). I'd love to hear if you got this to work for your application. (Or any other feedback about the Aerospike Node.js client!)

Comment: Thanks, @jan-hecking will give it a try